# "no such file to load -- fastercsv" error when trying to use fastercsv gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I installed the fastercsv gem like this:

```
sudo gem install fastercsv
```

Then in my controller I put this:

```
require 'fastercsv'
```

When I try to use it though, I get this error:

```
MissingSourceFile in Notes#export_data
no such file to load -- fastercsv
```

What have I done wrong? Thanks for reading.

EDIT:
I'm using Rails 2.3.5

```
rake gems
(in /Users/bh/rails_projects/notes)
 - [I] authlogic 
    - [R] activesupport 
 - [I] searchlogic 
    - [R] activerecord >= 2.0.0

I = Installed
F = Frozen
R = Framework (loaded before rails starts)
```

-

```
gem which fastercsv
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fastercsv-1.5.3/lib/fastercsv.rb
```

Comment: Paste the code where you've mentioned the file path.

Comment: @Shreyas Satish - Sorry, not entirely sure what you mean, I'm pretty new to RoR. I've added some stuff, hopefully that helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add it to your `config/environment.rb`

```
config.gem "fastercsv"
```

You'll see a few other lines mentioning `config.gem`, so stick it next to those. You might have to add `:version => 'x.x.x'`, if you have multiple versions of fastercsv and want to use a specific one.

Comment: I get this error when i add it to my environment.rb file `/config/environment.rb:17:in '<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method 'config' for main:Object (NameError)`

Comment: @VictorS are you in a Rails 2 or 3 project?

Comment: @VictorS If you're in Rails 3, this should be in your `Gemfile` as `gem 'fastercsv'`, and should not appear in your environment.rb file at all.

Comment: CSV is included into Rails 3 by default

Comment: @Edmund unless I'm mistaken `CSV` is not included by default in Rails 3. It's part of the standard library in Ruby 1.9, which was formerly `FasterCSV` in Ruby 1.8, which can just be required with `require 'csv'`.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to add the following line in the GemFile

gem 'fastercsv'

After doing that, remember to reboot your server application.

Comment: I was trying to use this gem in a Rake task.  I was surprised to find that I still needed to add this line to my Gemfile and do a `bundle` afterward before it would work.

Comment: I also needed to change my code to `require 'faster_csv'` (with an underscore), which I didn't expect.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Rails are you using?

If it's Rails 3 you'll need to specify it as a dependency of your application in the *Gemfile*:

```
gem 'fastercsv'
```

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned in the question but I'm using Rails 2.3.5